# How to Use Snort to detect NMAP default SYN scan?

Tags: firewall, snort

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916171/rule-for-capturing-syn-scanning#)  with the same question and it comes to this rule :

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (flags:S; msg:"NMAP TCP SYN"; sid: 1231213;)
```

but it is totally wrong, it will alert you on almost anything like a simple HTTP or HTTPS request.

I am going to restate the question this way :

Is there any way to detect scans by looking at a series of packets sends by a single IP , which has their SYN flag sets and it sends to at least 10 ports on the device in the Snort rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer to my question : YES.

Recently I come across a module named **[sfportscan](https://github.com/jasonish/snort/blob/master/doc/README.sfportscan)** which it have a lot's of options such as memory to save packets and analysis theme with time out and number of connections.

To Enable **sfportscan**, you should

**1**- Add this to **snort.cont** usually in **/etc/snort/** :

```
preprocessor sfportscan: proto { all } \
        scan_type  { all } \
        sense_level { high } \
        logfile { alert }
```

It will look for all protocols and all type of scans like SYN, Null , ... and log them in the log directory in the **alert** file (alert is an actual file name) which we've mentioned in option **logfile**. The space after and before brackets are important, snort parser issue an error without them.

**2**- Run `snort -c "/etc/snort/snort.conf" -T` to make sure all config are Okey.

**3**- Run `/etc/init.d/snort stop` and `/etc/init.d/snort start`   with some delay , to restart the Snort .

**4**- Open your alert file to see the alerts :

```
tail -f [Address to log Directory]/alert
```

**5**- Test if it create the log with **NMAP**, open another terminal in other machine and:

```
sudo nmap [Your Firewall or NIDS IP Address]
```

**6**- You should see somthing like this in tail file:

```
Time: 02/23-12:54:21.183932 
event_ref: 0
[Source ip address] -> [Destination ip address] (portscan) TCP Portscan
Priority Count: 9
Connection Count: 10
IP Count: 1
Scanner IP Range: [Destination ip address]:[Destination ip address]
Port/Proto Count: 10
Port/Proto Range: 981:12174
```

**My Note:**
Snort is a great IDS and it used in many free and even commercial products but it has a poor documentation and examples and YouTube introductions, it would be great if its community have more involvement in **Stackoverflow** , questions.